# Modify an existing DateTime object using a string containing a timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I've got a variable declared like such: `$var = new DateTime(null);`.

I want to change the time that `echo $var->format('g:i A');` outputs.

I want to achieve this solely by using a time string such as `07:30:28`.

How can I do this without re-creating a DateTime object ($var) each time? I can't think of a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime::modify() will do exactly what you want. It will quite happily accept a time in string format and apply it to the object:-

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify('07:30:28');
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/pTVDB).

Alternatively, you can do it all in one go:-

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->modify('07:30:28');
```